# Gradle Profile Slow Configuration

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

What is this `:` project that is taking > 75% of my configuration time?  The rest of the modules are really fast.[image]

Comment: Show us your `build.gradle` files please.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be your `assembleDebug` or similar build configuration profile.

What can you do about this?

1. Go through this medium post which explains in-depth technicalities for similar scenario: [How to decrease your gradle build time](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-to-decrease-your-gradle-build-time-by-65-310b572b0c43)
2. Go through the slides, they would help you for sure speeding up the builds, including your build configuration & overall project configuration as well: [Mastering Gradle 3.0](https://speakerdeck.com/snehpandya18/mastering-gradle-3)

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [gradle-profiler](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-profiler) with Chrome Trace option on ./gradlew help task. This will generate in depth detailed graphical report of configuration process. You will probably see what your build is busy doing.

see also: https://jakewharton.com/tracing-gradle-task-execution/

and: https://youtu.be/sQC9-Rj2yLI?t=2022